# Convert tabs in to select options (drop down)

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change tabs in to dropdown option. but work same like tabs.

*User select option tab content will be open*

http://jsfiddle.net/95rLrzg7/3/

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-3 bhoechie-tab-menu">
                   <div class="list-group">
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item active text-center" title="Open Order">
                       <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></h4><br/>Open Order
                     </a>
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center" title="Today Order">
                       <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></h4><br/>Today Order
                     </a>
                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center" title="Future Account">
                       <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></h4><br/>Future Order
                     </a>
                       <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-center" title="Past Order">
                       <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></h4><br/>Past Order
                     </a>
                   </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-9 bhoechie-tab">
                <!-- flight section -->
                <div class="bhoechie-tab-content active">
                    <h3>Open Order</h3>
</div>
</div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.bhoechie-tab-menu>div.list-group>a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var index = $(this).index();
            $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").removeClass("active");
            $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Kindly advice me any solution.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `I want to change tab in to select option`, could you elaborate your issue/expection

Comment: I want tabs in dropdown interface(dropdown option)

Comment: you mean accordian ,https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ ?